# Ajax content loading issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Following is my code which I am using to load contents dynamically. The issues which I am facing are the following:

Following code has now disabled `CTRL+CLICK` shortcode to open a url in a new tab. The new CSS and JS are not applying if they are not already exist in the previous page. Kindly let me know how can I resolve above mentioned issues?

```
 $(document.body).on("click", "nav a", function () {
      topen = $(this).attr("href");
      window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
      $("#main_wrapper").load( topen +" #main_wrapper > *");
      return false;
 });
```

Comment: If you are changing the page dynamically why would you want to allow the user to `CTRL+click` to open a new tab? In this case you are completely overriding the default behavior of the link.

Comment: @HJ05 Becuase I am applying it on main menu of the website and some user wants to keep new pages open in the tabs. So how can do it if user clicks via `CTRL + CLICK`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is modify the handler to use prevent default instead of returning false. Then you can check how the user activated the button and can act accordingly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').on('click', function(e) {
        if(e.ctrlKey || e.button === 1) {
            return;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        // Do the stuff when the anchor is just clicked.
    });
});
```

You can examine the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4kygv9co/)

In terms of the JS and CSS not applying we would need a working example of this to be of more assistance.

Comment: Thanks for js I have written the code which can dynamically load or unload CSS and Javascript. I guess its the only right way. I was thinking before let only load the new css and js which are not present in the current page from where the request being made to open a new page.